# ¿Error SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1366 insertando CVS con PHP Mysql?

Tags: php, mysql, excel

Tengo una página que deja importar CVS a Mysql base de datos, pero cuando en el CVS hay algún simbolo que ocupa 4 bites en vez de 3, me sale este error:

> ```
> SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1366 Incorrect string value: '\x96
> 0014...'
> ```

Y la importación de las filas que contienen algún simbolo cómo barra `-`, slash `/` u otro, se suspende.

¿Cómo lo soluciono para poder importar todo? De collation tengo `utf8_general_ci`, utilizo PDO prepared statements para hacer el `INSERT`. Mi código:

```
 $sql = "
INSERT INTO `lithuania_customers_2016`
(`customer_db_id`, `user_id`, `user_email`)
VALUES (?, ?, ?);";
$stmt = $pdo->prepare($sql);
$stmt->execute(array(
   $emapData[0],
   $emapData[1],
   $emapData[2]
));
```

Comment: podrías poner el código que carga las querys en la BB.DD?? Seguramente lo arregles escapando los caracteres

Comment: @CarlosGª-muñoz Ya está el código..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cuando creas la conexión a mysql debes especificar el juego de caracteres no basta con poner las tablas y campos en utf8. También la conexión tiene su propio juego de caracteres.

Algo asi:

```
<?php
$db = new pdo(
'mysql:host=127.0.0.1;port=3306;dbname=mysql;charset=utf8',
'user',
'password',
array(PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND => "SET NAMES utf8") 
);
```

Desde mysql también es posible establecer el valor a utf8 en las variables de entorno.

Comment: Ya lo tenia puesto exactamente como lo pones tu en la conexion... :/ alguna otra sugerencia? Pero se agradece tu respuesta.

Comment: Prueba tambien con la codificación **utf8mb4**, es posible que esto resuelva el problema.

Comment: Me da error: `Incorrect datetime value 0000-00-00 00:00:00 at line 6`, mi tabla es muy grande 46 columnas, hay de todo: timestamp, text, la mayoria varchar.

Comment: Puedes hacer la siguiente consulta y pegar el resultado para que nos hagamos una idea de la tabla, **SHOW CREATE TABLE nombre_tabla**